# How to use metismenu with typescript & webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

In my navigation module I'm trying to call the .metisMenu(); function.

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import { Route } from '../../router';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

interface NavMenuParams {
    route: KnockoutObservable<Route>;
}

class NavMenuViewModel {
    public route: KnockoutObservable<Route>;

    constructor(params: NavMenuParams) {
        this.route = params.route;
        $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
    }
}

export default { viewModel: NavMenuViewModel, template: require('./nav-menu.html') };
```

I've installed `@types/metismenu` and included it in `tsconfig.json`. Doing this will give me full intellisense in VSCode and no red squiggles. Bundling with webpack gives no errors. However when the navigation module loads it returns with the error `metisMenu is not a function`. I've tried to add `import metisMenu from 'metismenu';` however it's defaulting to the `@types/metismenu` directory and not the main `metismenu` source. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you also include jquery in your HTML page with a script tag?

Comment: It's bundled in webpack as a global variable.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?